New-AzAutomationSchedule - Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I'm running into a frustrating problem trying to get an Azure Automation Runbook to schedule Azure Automation jobs.
My runbook is trying to execute the New-AzAutomationSchedule and Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook.  No matter what paramters I'm passing, I keep getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I'm trying this with PowerShell 5.1, 7.1, and 7.2 runtimes.  I'm mainly using PowerShell 5.1 because I need to use Invoke-ProcessASDatabase from the SqlServer module and that's the only runtime that recognizes that method.
To rule out any potential issues with the variables I'm passing, I resorted to just hardcoding some valid values to the method calls, for instance...
New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "account1" -ResourceGroupName "resource1" -Name "Test-Daily-Schedule" -StartTime "23:00" -DayInterval 1

Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName "account1" -ResourceGroupName "resource1" -ScheduleName "Test-Daily-Schedule" -RunbookName "runbook1"

The full error for one of these calls is:
New-AzAutomationSchedule : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
At line:122 char:17 + ... New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $Automati ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + 
CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [New-AzAutomationSchedule], 
NullReferenceException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.NewAzureAutomationSchedule

I am relatively new to PowerShell, so I suppose I could be doing something really boneheaded and just not seeing it.  Any help would be appreciated in figuring this out.
Thanks!
Adding my test program for reference:
$Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "ps_name"

Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "***"

$AutomationAccountName = "account1"
$ResourceGroupName = "resource1"
$StartTime = "23:00"
$TimeZone = ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local).Id

$context = Get-AzContext

Write-Output "Scheduling job"
Try
{
    New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name "Schedule01" -StartTime $StartTime -TimeZone $TimeZone -OneTime -DefaultProfile $context
}
Catch
{
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}

Write-Output "Registering runbook"
Try
{
    Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ScheduleName "Schedule01" -RunbookName "runbook1"
}
Catch
{
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}


I have test your New-AzAutomationSchedule in powershell 7.4.2, it works well.

you run this in runbook? or your local PC?

I'm running this from within a runbook in the PowerShell 5.1 runtime that's part of Azure Automation.  I've also tried 7.1 and 7.2.  Doesn't appear there's a more recent version of PowerShell for Azure Automation, though.

if you are in runbook, try to use New-AutomationSchedule instead of New-AzAutomationSchedule. Can you try it? also can you show the code which you connect to azure in the runbook? the way you connect to azure may lead to this issue.

I did try that, but whatever module has that method is not present in my environments.  Looks like it's an older version of the New-AzAutomationSchedule.
I'll post my test code above.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error message Object reference not set to an instance of an object usually indicates that a variable or object is null or uninitialized. Additionally, it might indicate that you have not connected an identity.
You can use the script below to connect using Identity and catch any errors that are thrown within the script using the try and catch function.
I have used the runbook runtime version 5.1.

    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
    Set-AzContext -Subscription "Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription"
    
    Try {
        New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "venkatautomation" -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -Name "Test-Daily-Schedule" -StartTime "23:00" -DayInterval 1
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
    
    Try {
        Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName "venkatautomation" -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -ScheduleName "Test-Daily-Schedule" -RunbookName "Venkatrunbook"
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }


Once the runbook is executed, the schedule will be created

Reference:  Azure runbook ending with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Thanks for the help.  The object reference issue is gone, but now I'm having problems setting the context.
The error I get is "Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription".  I've tried both the subscription name and id for my automation account and for high level azure subscription (the one represented with a key icon).
I also don't see any of the output you are getting in your test pane.  I just get a list of environments.
I also tried using the credentials from Get-AutomationPSCredential that I use for the Invoke-ProcessASDatabase call (see original post), w/o luck...

Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'UsernamePasswordCredential authentication failed: Unsupported User Type 'Unknown'. Please see https://aka.ms/msal-net-up.
See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/usernamepasswordcredential/troubleshoot'
UsernamePasswordCredential authentication failed: Unsupported User Type 'Unknown'. Please see https://aka.ms/msal-net-up.

Hi @CurtC, if you are unable to connect using connect-azaccount, please try this command instead: az login --identity --username "Automation Identity object ID".

Refer this MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hrw-run-runbooks?tabs=win-extn-hrw%2CLin-extn-hrw%2Csa-mi#runbook-auth-managed-identities for using managed identity in automation account

Is that possible to do within the runbook?  I get an error that az is not a valid cmdlet.
I tried this on the command line in Azure Cloud Shell as a test and did get back quite a bit of information.  But Connect-AzAccount works fine in the shell too.

Yes, Its possible , Here is the managed identity using Azure CLI and PowerShell with managed identities.
Before running the az commands in runbook , you need to install Az module first.

Refer the stack link  for az login in runbook.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thanks @Venkat for all the help!  I did finally get this to work going back to using my service principal that I'm using with my SqlServer calls...
$Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "ps_name"
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId "..." -Credential $Credential
$AzureContext = Get-AzContext
$SubscriptionId = $AzureContext.Subscription.Id
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

